# Matlab own fft2 without loops

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a problem.

I have a task to write an own fft2 without using for-loops in Matlab.
There is a formula for computing this task:

F(u,v) = sum (0 to M-1) {sum(o to N-1) {f(m,n)*e^(-i*2pi*(um/M + vn/N))}}

Or for better reading:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3808/qs3r9ogz_png.htm

It is easy to do it with two for-loops but I have no idea how to do this without these loops, absolutely no idea.
We get no help by the teaching personal. They don't even give a hint or a reference to a book, where we could read about it.

Now, I want to try to get help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the matrix form of DFT? have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix

You can do something similar in order to get a matrix form for 2D DFT.
You need to transformation matrices. The first is a N-by-N DFT matrix that operates on the columns of `f`, as explained in the link above. Next you need another M-byM DFT matrix the operates on the rows of `f`. Finally, you transformed signal is given by

```
F = Wm * f * Wn;
```

without any loops.
Note that the DFT matrix can be constructed also without loop by using something like

```
(1:M)*((1:M)')
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be very good, but there is a lack of knowledge on my side. I do not know, how to create these DFT-Matrices. I have this formula. Won't I need this and if, how do I use it. This issue is hard to grab for me.

Comment: @user3556115 Follow the link I provided. The DFT matrix is defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little correction in Thp's answer: `(1:M)*((1:M)')` is not the right way to create the matrix, but `(1:M)'*(1:M)` is the correct way.